# Missing Custom Attriubutes

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, custom-attributes

In C#, one can use reflection to obtain the attributes on a member `m` via `m.CustomAttributes` (see [the documentation for this property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.customattributes(v=vs.110).aspx)).  However, this approach seems to miss three custom attributes on the `GetType` method of `Object` (see [the Object in the Reference Source for .NET Framework 4.6.1](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,d9262ceecc1719ab)):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
  public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
      var desiredCustomAttributes = typeof(object)
        .GetMethods()
        .First(m => m.Name == "GetType")
        .CustomAttributes
        .Select(ca => ca.ToString())
        .Where(s =>
          s.Contains("Pure") ||
          s.Contains("ResourceExposure") ||
          s.Contains("MethodImplAttribute"));
      var n = desiredCustomAttributes.Count();
      Console.WriteLine("Expected: 3");
      Console.WriteLine("  Actual: " + n); // prints "  Actual: 0"
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

> Why do these three custom attributes not show up?

<strike>Maybe it has something to do with the fact that it is an [external](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5.aspx) method?</strike>

Actually, being external has nothing to do with it.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;
namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
  public class ResourceExposureAttributeOnConstructor {
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
    public ResourceExposureAttributeOnConstructor() { }
  }
  public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
      var n = typeof(object)
        .GetConstructors()
        .First()
        .CustomAttributes
        .Select(ca => ca.ToString())
        .Where(s => s.Contains("ResourceExposure"))
        .Count();
      Console.WriteLine("Expected: 1");
      Console.WriteLine("  Actual: " + n); // prints "  Actual: 0"
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not because the method is external. Tried with a user defined class:

```
class MyAttr : Attribute { }
class Program
{
    [Pure]
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.AppDomain)]
    [MethodImpl]
    [MyAttr]
    public void Foo() { }
}
```

`.CustomAttributes` returns `MyAttr` only. I think it's simply because FCL don't threat the three attributes as custom attributes. Looking into the source code, `MethodInfo.CustomAttributes` finally invokes `MetadataImport.EnumCustomAttributes`, where an external method is called.

```
[SecurityCritical]
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
private static extern void _Enum(IntPtr scope, int type, int parent, out MetadataEnumResult result);
```

I didn't debug into it, but I think it makes sense that this method knows some built-in attributes and excludes them from custom attributes.

**EDIT** `PureAttribute` and `ResourceExposureAttribute` are conditionally built, that's why you can't get them.

```
[Conditional("RESOURCE_ANNOTATION_WORK")]
public sealed class ResourceExposureAttribute : Attribute

[Conditional("CONTRACTS_FULL")]
public sealed class PureAttribute : Attribute
```

It seems that `MethodImplAttribute` is special.

Comment: What does it mean for an attribute to be "built-in"?  One custom attribute that is returned from `GetType` is `__DynamicallyInvokable` (cf. [this SE Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550749/what-is-the-dynamicallyinvokable-attribute-for)).  The fact that this custom attribute shows up in the list but is _not_ in the source suggests to me that it is more "built-in" than these other three.

Comment: So suppose that the actual behavior is the expected behavior.  Then how can one know what types of custom attributes will be returned from a call to `CustomAttributes` and what types will not?

Comment: @TysonWilliams I mean, the definition of `custom attribute` is made by FCL. Obviously user-defined attributes are custom. But built-in attributes are not guaranteed.

Comment: @TysonWilliams I'm afraid you can't find an official list of custom attributes rule. Just curious, why do you need to know if a built-in attribute is custom or not?

Comment: Trying to infer dependencies of a given type.  `Object` is clearly dependent on these three attributes.  Someone compiled `mscorelib`, which of course includes `Object`.  The compiler needs to know that `Object` is dependent on these three types.  How does it do that?

Comment: @TysonWilliams Here what's the meaning of `dependent on sth`? It's just like you define two classes A and B in the same assembly, B derives from A, and A has one property whose type is B. I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97826/discussion-between-tyson-williams-and-danny-chen).